# How to visible true menustrip's toolstripmenuitem and its sub menu?

Tags: c#

i have a menustrip in which i have inserted some toolstripmenuitem and three sub menus.At the time of login i want to make `visible=true` for all the items in menu strip. but i am unable to do so.this is my code.

**Code**:

```
private void SetToolStripItems(ToolStripItemCollection dropDownItems)
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (object obj in dropDownItems)
                {
                    if (obj.GetType().Equals(typeof(ToolStripMenuItem)))
                    {
                        ToolStripMenuItem subMenu = (ToolStripMenuItem)obj;
                        if (subMenu.HasDropDownItems)
                        {
                            subMenu.Visible = true;
                        }
                        else // Do the desired operations here.
                        {
                            subMenu.Visible = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //
            }
        }
```

Comment: Good formatting is always your friend..

Comment: Is this winforms? why are you unable to do it?

Comment: yes i am working on it.

Comment: What doesn't work? What is the problem? Do any of the items become visible? If so, are they already visible by default or is some of your code actually doing what you want?

Comment: look at the time of form load i want to visible false menustrip and its items. and after login i want to visible true. dats it.

Comment: and on the basis of user's limitation i want hide some items in it. for example it the user is Admin then all items will we visible to him and it the user is local then some item automatically visible false.

Comment: common guys where r u all?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:
Hide   Copy Code

```
subitem.Visible = true;
```

try:
Hide   Copy Code

```
subitem.Available = true;
```

See the remarks on this MSDN page, describing the difference between .Visible and .Available:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripitem.available.aspx[^]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripitem.available.aspx[%5E])